# Options for iOS 4.2.1 Development in 2015

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

I have an old 2G iPod Touch for which I'd like to develop a very simple application.  I managed to install Xcode 3.2.5 (the first to include the 4.2 SDK) onto my Mac that runs 10.10.4, but it says it isn't compatible when I run it. Next I tried Xcode 4.4.1 (the most recent that can target iOS 4.2), but it also fails to run. So, I'm thinking that Apples tools might be a lost cause when it comes to development for 4.2.1 if I'm not willing to downgrade my Mac to an earlier OSX version.

Do I have any other options for developing an iOS 4.2.1 app using one or more of OSX 10.10.4, Windows 10, and Ubuntu 14.04? Are options like Xamarin more flexible when it comes to the iOS versions they can target?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Xamarin relies on the underlying XCode tools and SDKs, so it will likely have the same problems.

Comment: Jason is right about Xamarin, they depend on Xcode and thus have the same limitations (so iOS 6.0 is the earliest). People that I know that are still coding for 'older' iOS are mainly using VMs to run older versions of OS-X and Xcode.

Comment: I hadn't considered VMs, so thanks for planting that idea. I think I'll try OSX 10.7 and Xcode 4.2.1 in a VM.